# How do I set up an outlook message rule that matches only first name?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have tons of junk emails from our ticketing system, most of which I just ignore but occasionally someone will mention something like 'Simon could you take a look at this?'

I want to filter these into a subfolder, if it contains the word 'simon', but unfortunately every single message ends with something like

"Message sent to users John Smith and Simon Johnson"

so if I add a rule to detect 'Simon' it moves every single email to the folder.

If I exclude 'Simon Johnson' then it moves no e-mails.

Is there a way to make it require >1 instance of Simon, or match only Simon and ignore Simon Johnson?

Answer (score 1):

A `VBA` script like the following could do the job:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoubleSimonMessageRule(newMail As Outlook.mailItem)
    Dim a() As String          '  we convert the mail body to an array of string
    Dim EntryID As String
    Dim StoreID As Variant
    Dim mi As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim dest As String
    Dim destFldr As Outlook.Folder
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim iMatch As Integer

    Const pattern = "Simon"
    Const dest1 = "Simon1"     '  destination folder for 1 match
    Const destAny = "SimonAny" '  destination folder for 2+ matches

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler


    '  we have to access the new mail via an application reference
    '  to avoid security warnings
    EntryID = newMail.EntryID
    StoreID = newMail.Parent.StoreID

    Set mi = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryID, StoreID)

    a = Split(mi.body, vbCrLf)
    iMatch = 0
    For I = LCase(a) To UCase(a)
        If InStr(1, a(I), pattern, vbTextCompare) Then
            iMatch = iMatch + 1
        End If
    Next I

    If iMatch < 1 Then
        '  this should not happen, provided our rule is configured properly
        Err.Raise 1, , "No " & pattern & " in Mail"
    ElseIf iMatch = 1 Then
        dest = dest1
    ElseIf iMatch > 1 Then
        dest = destAny
    End If

    Set destFldr = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(dest)
    mi.Move destFldr
    ' mi.Delete    '  not sure about this!
    Set mi = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Use the Outlook Rule Assistant to call this script for incoming mails which have "Simon" in their mail body.